# Copy animation to another object

Tags: animation, collada

Hey Blender Community,

I have two models with two different animations. I want the woman to have the same animation as the man with the green t-shirt. How can I achieve this? I'm new to Blender and would be happy for any help.

Here is a video:

https://streamable.com/rv1j8o

You can download the 2 models here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/13SzH2TMhz_qaO7zSUZ4qn6RWd2PJyj0H/view?usp=sharing

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: do the 2 armatures have the same bones? Otherwise you'll need to parent the second object to the armature of the first object

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Your two dae armatures have different bone names (and perhaps position and other subtle differences), so therein the challenge.   There appears to be similar structure so it might work.  I might first try renaming the bones on one or the other armature to match.  I have written a python script that you might be able to use as example (diff bone names, however), else a laborious process.  Ask and I'll post it as an answer.  Then in the ActionEditor, you can simply use the dropdown to change  'Armature.001' from 'Armature.001Action' to '_6_15_tAction'